# Getting Error while running the XCtestCase in Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xctestcase

Please do help me on this scenario. I saw several post related to this, but could not able to resolve the issue occur while running XCTestCase.

I am trying to add XCUnitTest case in a existing project .While running the test case I am facing following issue.

Console shows:

```
Failed to load test bundle from file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Testƒ.app/PlugIns/Test.xctest: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/TestTests.xctest/TestTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/TestTests: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Tests'
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Tests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Tests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Test: code signature invalid for '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest/Tests'
, NSBundlePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/PlugIns/Tests.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
 libXCTestBundleInject Arguments:
2020-03-30 08:28:13.136091+0100 Test[3588:930021]   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/Test
2020-03-30 08:28:13.136135+0100 Test[3588:930021]   -NSTreatUnknownArgumentsAsOpen
2020-03-30 08:28:13.136163+0100 Test[3588:930021]   NO
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140427+0100 Test[3588:930021]   -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140485+0100 Test[3588:930021]   YES
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140518+0100 Test[3588:930021] libXCTestBundleInject Environment:
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140797+0100 Test[3588:930021]   CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS = 0
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140855+0100 Test[3588:930021]   CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS = 0
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140923+0100 Test[3588:930021]   XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140954+0100 Test[3588:930021]   XCInjectBundleInto = /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/Test
2020-03-30 08:28:13.140983+0100 Test[3588:930021]   DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH = /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/Frameworks:
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141011+0100 Test[3588:930021]   XCTestConfigurationFilePath = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC15C4BC-599B-4D5A-AEE6-FBF2A3CFAEA1/tmp/TestTests-0F2F6E4A-CB44-476E-8046-C61EB392B443.xctestconfiguration
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141329+0100 Test[3588:930021]   MTC_CRASH_ON_REPORT = 1
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141409+0100 Test[3588:930021]   SHELL = /bin/sh
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141443+0100 Test[3588:930021]   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8F3581C-6EC3-4930-AC50-105B5B6A3BD6/Test.app/Frameworks
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141494+0100 Test[3588:930021]   SQLITE_ENABLE_THREAD_ASSERTIONS = 1
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141562+0100 Test[3588:930021]   CLASSIC = 0
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141610+0100 Test[3588:930021]   NSUnbufferedIO = YES
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141659+0100 Test[3588:930021]   OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE = YES
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141708+0100 Test[3588:930021]   PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141740+0100 Test[3588:930021]   CFFIXED_USER_HOME = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC15C4BC-599B-4D5A-AEE6-FBF2A3CFAEA1
2020-03-30 08:28:13.141791+0100 Test[3588:930021]   HOME = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC15C4BC-599B-4D5A-AEE6-FBF2A3CFAEA1
2020-03-30 08:28:13.142947+0100 Test[3588:930021]   TMPDIR = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CC15C4BC-599B-4D5A-AEE6-FBF2A3CFAEA1/tmp/
2020-03-30 08:28:13.143044+0100 Test[3588:930021]   USER = mobile
2020-03-30 08:28:13.143075+0100 Test[3588:930021]   XPC_SERVICE_NAME = UIKitApplication:com.btor.Test[0xca1c][60]
2020-03-30 08:28:13.143142+0100 Test[3588:930021]   LOGNAME = mobile
2020-03-30 08:28:13.143170+0100 Test[3588:930021]   __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0:0
```

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: support till iOS 12 .Mac OS version :10.13.6 (17G65)

Comment: And your code signing is working OK?

Comment: Yes , it is working , In same project I can able to run UITestcase

Comment: Hey @trojanfoe  , I am able to solve this error by setting my Code signing Entitlement to blank in test target .Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

Hey I solved this by setting my Code signing Entitlement to blank in test target .